# Free managed memory allocation from unmanaged code

Tags: c#, interop, unmanaged, managed

I'd like to do `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` in managed code, fill it with data, and pass that memory block to unmanaged (C++) code that will then be responsible for freeing it.

Under the hood, `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` calls `LocalAlloc` (and, I'm guessing, `LocalLock`). But in order for the unmanaged code to call LocalFree, it needs the HLOCAL returned by `LocalAlloc`, which `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` doesn't provide.

I'm not necessarily restricted to using `AllocHGlobal`; the high level goal is to let the managed code allocate memory that the unmanaged code and then read and free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a handle, not since Windows version 3.  Calling LocalFree() on the pointer is fine, as the [Windows SDK article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366723%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) shows in its example.  Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem and CoTaskMemFree() are the better mouse trap here.

Comment: Ah yes. The Marshal.AllocHGlobal allocs with LMEM_FIXED, which returns a direct pointer. Thanks.